# How to avoid code repetition when specifying the 'highlight' and 'unhighlight' methods in jQuery's validation plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider this application of the jQuery validation plugin:

```
(function($) {
  'use strict';
  $('form[data-behavior="validate"]').validate({
    errorElement: 'span',
    ignore: ':hidden, .select-dropdown',
    normalizer: function(value) {
      if (!value) value = '';

      if ($(this).is('[data-currency-mask]')) {
        return value.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/,/g, '');
      }

      return value;
    },
    highlight: function(element) {
      $(element).addClass('invalid');
      $(element.form).find('label[for=' + element.id + ']').addClass('invalid');
    },
    unhighlight: function(element) {
      $(element).removeClass('invalid');
      $(element.form).find('label[for=' + element.id + ']').removeClass('invalid');
    }
  });
})(jQuery);
```

This custom validator adds/removes the error class `"invalid"` to/from both the element and its label. The result looks like this (where Materialize.css is used):

[image]

There is some code repetition in the `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions, which I'd like to eliminate; in addition, it seems like I could make use of the `errorClass` attribute (cf. https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/) instead of hard-coding `'invalid'` everywhere.

I've tried setting `errorClass: 'invalid'` in the object passed to `.validate()`, and then using `errorClass` instead of `'invalid'` in the `highlight` and `unhighlight` methods, but this appears not to work. How can I refactor this code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment because people won't flame my answers or what ever it takes to get reputation.

But, the first thing I notice is

`if (!value) value = '';`

should be

`if (!value) { value = ''; }`

which could also be initialized with

`value = value || '';`

or, depending what version of ECMAscript you're using, you could even save a line of code and  initialize it in the parameters

`normalizer: function(value = '')`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters